# Getting Available Date/Times For Attendees And Avoid Conflict

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, join, subquery

```
+------------+  +---------------+  +--------------+
| attendees  |  | attendee_times|  | meeting_times|
+------------+  +---------------+  +--------------+ 
| attendee_id|  | at_id         |  |              |
| name       |  | attendee_id   |  | meeting_id   |
+------------+  | date_1        |  | recipient_id |
                | time_1        |  | sender_id    |
                | date_2        |  | meeting_date |
                | time_2        |  | meeting_time |
                +---------------+  +--------------+
```

I have to generate a semi-automated meeting planner. Users enter their two optimal dates/times (attendee_times) and the system will look at all other attendees who picked similar dates/times and create a pending meeting between them.

However, the system has to make sure that a matching attendee does not have an existing meeting (meeting_times) already with the same date/time. An attendee can either be a recipient or sender so attendee_id can be either foreign key.